# Filter TreeView by Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have some `TreeView` and I would like filter it by `Text` field. I have implement method for it.

```
private bool FilterTreeNode(string searchText, TreeNode node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes)
    {
        var childNodeResult = FilterTreeNode(searchText, childNode);

        if (childNodeResult == false)
        {
            node.Nodes.Remove(childNode);
        }
    }

    return node.Nodes == null || node.Nodes.Count < 1
        ? node.Text.ToLower().Contains(searchText)
        : true;
}
```

And on one of the iterations, this method throws an exception, because the method gets `node = null`.
Where I can do mistake?

Comment: Don't remove nodes while you are iterating. Maybe keep a list of nodes to delete and do the delete after the check

Comment: Two bugs.  The Remove() call causes nodes to be skipped, that's a bit hard to notice.  Append `.OfType<TreeNode>()` to make a copy that can't be affected by Remove.  The node.Nodes == null test is too late, you already used foreach on it.  Get out early.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are removing the `childNode` from the collection you are iterating through as part of your `foreach` loop.

You might be able to get around this by checking if the node is null at the top of the method before proceeding, but I think in general it might be more reliable to instead build up a new TreeNode which includes the items you want to keep and return that, rather than removing the unwanted items from the original TreeNode?